# Aurelia aurelia-fetch-client and with JSON POST

Tags: json, aurelia, stringify

I have the following code which works is working well:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';


@inject(HttpClient)
export class Items {
  heading = 'Items';
  apiKey = "";

  constructor(http) {
    http.configure(config => {
      config
        .useStandardConfiguration()
        .withBaseUrl('https://testme.com/api/')
          .withDefaults({
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'X-Requested-With': 'Fetch'
            }
          })
    });

    this.http = http;
  }

attach() {

let auth = {
  Username:"admin",
  Password:"1234"
};

return this.http.fetch('auth', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(auth),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.apiKey = response.APIKey;
      console.log(response);
});
```

However, if replace the `body: JSON.stringify(auth)` line with `json(auth)` which is I believe the correct way to JSON serialise an object using the Aurelia JSON helper, my API throws a bad request.

Is there anything different that the helper does vs JSON.stringify ?

Comment: Is your API at the same domain as your website? If so, try to get rid of the absolute path (https:// ) in your config function. I can see that due to some reason the request body gets empty with absolute URLs, while your example works fine if I make a local request...

Comment: No the API is at a different URL, which does actually give me a CORS problem, which I've disabled in Safari for the time being.

Comment: Please run a web proxy (e.g. fiddler) and see what exactly happens there. Then add the result to your question. Do you ever see your POST request or maybe just one with OPTIONS method?

Comment: OK so I resolved this issue. Created a gulp proxy to my API and that fixed the issue.

Comment: I am getting a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) error with the above code , against ASP.Net WEB API !

Comment: @Mikhail I'm actually trying to figure out an issue right now which is doing exactly this.  I am supplying the method: 'POST' option, but my network tab is reporting that it's using the OPTIONS method instead, with no body.  I have tried using both JSON.stringify() and json() (doesn't seem related, but...)

Comment: @Anj Most probably you are having CORS issues. With OPTIONS request your browser is trying to figure out if it's allowed to send other requests to external domain https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @Mikhail Yep, got Web API configured to allow CORS properly; thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `json` function calls JSON.stringify, but also adds `Content-Type: application/json` to the headers. I'm wondering if the error that's thrown for you might be due to the header already existing since you're explicitly adding it.

Try using `json` again, but this time remove your code that modifies the headers to add that Content-Type.

See [here](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/blob/a7e715fe00b72eb457fa92df04a35e2eac0b3326/src/util.js) for the code for that json function.